# rational homotopy type and cohomological vanishing for local systems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a (smooth) algebraic variety of complex dimension $n$, if for each local system $L$ with rational coefficients,  we have
the vanishing $H^{i}(X,L)=0$, $\forall i>k$ for some fixed $k\geq 0$. What information can we get for the rational homotopy type of $X$?

For example, is $X$ rationally homotopy to an $k$ dimentional CW-complex?

This question is motivated by results on affine algebraic varieties. The vanishing above (for $k=\textrm{dim}X$) is the Artin vanishing. The fact that a smooth affine algebraic variety of complex dimension $n$ is homotopy to a CW complex whose cells has dimension $\leq n$ follows form Morse theory.